# How to create unique constraint on 4 fields grouped 2 and 2?

Tags: unique, postgresql-9.1, unique-constraint

I am trying to create a relations system in my web application which will rely on a single join table defined as

```sql
CREATE TABLE associations (
  associationId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  fromTable varchar(255),
  fromId int,
  toTable varchar(255),
  toId int  
);
```

Now I need to make it so that `(fromTable, fromId, toTable, toId)` is unique for each row, but what I need is not as easy as creating a simple unique constraint on those four fields.

For example, I would need this query

```sql
INSERT INTO associations (fromTable, fromId, toTable, toId)
VALUES ('table1', 1, 'table2', 2);
```

to fail if the table already contains a row with the tuple `('table1', 1, 'table2', 2)` **OR** `('table2', 2, 'table1', 1)`

Is it possible to achieve this through constraints or do I need to implement the check manually before trying to insert the data?

EDIT:

@Germann Arlington suggested to do this using a trigger to insert the relation in both ways, but wouldn't this 'cause an endless trigger loop, if I do an insert in the same table that triggered the trigger?

Comment: I don't think that you can do it in single constraint. Though what you could do is add a trigger that will insert a reversed record for you when you insert a direct dependency and then standard unique key constraint will work.

Comment: I see.. thanks for your advice, I did not think about using a trigger.